# Searching through a contact list for given criteria

Tags: java, optimization, homework, search

I have been staring at this code for awhile now and I am thinking there is a way to optimize it (namely the `if`-`else` statement with the `for`-loops).

Additionally, this needs to be done with an array list as that is my assignment requirement. I have all my code working, and it is not due for a few days, so I am looking for ways to improve it while extending my learning beyond the classroom.

The `numberOfContacts` variable is fed into the method from the main method, which gets the count from another method that reads through a text file to get the number of contacts.

```
/**
 * search method searches through the contact list for a given criteria
 * and displays all results.
 * @param searchString is type String.
 * @param type is type String.
 * @param numberOfContacts is type int.
 * @param contacts is type Person[].
 */
public static void search(String searchString, String type, int numberOfContacts, Person[] contacts) {
    // Initialize variables for results
    int found = 0;
    int[] results = new int[numberOfContacts];

    // Determine the type of search
    if (type.equals("name")) {
        // Search by name
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfContacts; x++) {
            if (contacts[x].getName().contains(searchString)) {
                results[found] = x;
                found++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Search by phone
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfContacts; x++) {
            if (contacts[x].getPhone().contains(searchString)) {
                results[found] = x;
                found++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Display the search results
    System.out.println("\n\t**************");
    System.out.println("\tSearch Results");
    System.out.println("\t**************");
    System.out.println("Found " + found + " results containing \"" + searchString + "\":");
    System.out.println();

    if (found > 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < found; x++) {
            System.out.println(contacts[results[x]].getName() + "\t" + contacts[results[x]].getPhone());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are limited to use only Arrays, you can create a interface like this

```
public static interface Checker {
    public boolean check(Person p, String searchString);
}
```

Create a Checker for every type of comparison you want.

And compare with the Checker

```
for (int x = 0; x < numberOfContacts; x++) {
    if (checker.check(contacts[x], searchString)) {
        results[found] = x;
        found++;
    }
}
```

You can see a working example here (with your classes and methos): http://ideone.com/2C6kei

Note:
With this method is easy to expand the search criteria (as you see in the example, with a anywhere Checker).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should clarify what your homework statement exactly says: a Java "array list" is something like

   ```
   List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>()
   ```

   while `Person[] persons` is a Java "array".
2. Java is not Fortran or C; there is no need for the argument `int numberOfContacts`, so you can just call `contacts.length` to get the size of an array.  If you use an `ArrayList`, it is `contacts.size()` instead.
3. When you print out the results, there is no need for `if (found > 0)` since the `for`-loop will not be executed a single time if there is nothing to execute.

   Other than that the algorithm looks fine; I don't see much to optimize.
   Optional suggestions:
4. Instead of using an `if`-statement to check the `type`, you can look into the Java `switch`-statement.  That would be useful especially if you many types: "name", "phone", "address", "age", etc.
5. Instead of using hardcoded strings for the type, look into the `enum`:

   ```
   public enum ContactField {
       NAME, PHONE;
   }
   ```

   and instead of passing an argument of type `String`, use the type `ContactField`.  The `switch`-statement works with `String` and `enum`.

**SOME EDITS ONE YEAR LATER:**

6. In the `for`-loop, use `int i` instead of `int x`.  It is just a convention, but everyone uses it.
7. "Separation of concern": have your `search` method only return the list of matches.  If you want to print them, print the returned list elsewhere.  You want to break your code in small methods so that each one can be reused.  For example, you might use your `search` method in a web server framework and you would need to send the matches over to the user's web page instead of printing them to the console.

Since Java 8 came out, you could instead use:

```
public Stream<Person> searchByName(String name) {
    return Arrays.stream(persons).filter(person -> person.getName().contains(targetName));
}

public Stream<Person> searchByPhone(String phone) {
    Arrays.stream(persons).filter(person -> person.getPhone().contains(targetPhone));
}
```

and then you can whatever you want with that stream.  For example,

```
personsStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

However, since your instructor asked you to use arrays, it will probably take another 15 years before he/she switches over to the Java 8.